# Arranging the ingredient-quantity data in a single row, to be retrieved elsewhere

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I want to implement a table on Google Sheets that contains rows with different data, two of these fields to be related arrays and I'd like to know best way to implement it. There are three different sheets, named Recipies, Ingredients and Dishes. Recipies contain the name of the dish and the list of ingredients, Ingredients contains the nutritional info of each ingredient, and Dishes contains the actual nutritional info of each serving.

Recipies Sheet I want to keep it as readable and visual as possible:

```
Name  Time   Ingredients
Pasta 20min  {150 spaghetti, 30 sauce, 5 marjoram, 20 cheese}
```

Dishes:

```
Name  Prot.  Carb.  Fat  KCal
Pasta    x      x     x     x
```

I want to get the recipies' ingredients and quantities data, lookup for its nutritional content and sum the quantities on the Dishes sheet. The Ingredients sheet looks like:

```
Ingredient Prot.  Carb.  Fat KCal
Pasta         x      x     x    x
Marjoram      x      x     x    x
```

I know how to get row data from a different sheet if ingredients and quantities are arrenged in two rows and each one in different columns, like to sum the total protein in the dish:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(LOOKUP(F5:K5;Ingredients!$B$4:$B$1000;Ingredients!$D$4:$D$1000)*((F6:K6)/100)))/E5
```

The problem I have is I want to have in a single row the list of ingredients and the quantity used like {150 spaghetti, 30 sauce, 5 marjoram, 20 cheese}. I want to keep it readable at a glance. I tried to use an array but dont know how to make it work.

How can I best arrange data to be in a single row and be able to use it to lookup data on other sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would enter data for each recipe in structured form, such as an ingredient-quantity table, and then *display* it in readable form, by building a text string from the data using `join` or similar. General idea is  that structured data should be the source of information, while the things displayed for human consumption are derived from that.

But if you insist on using strings such as "150 spaghetti, 30 sauce, 5 marjoram, 20 cheese" as source of information, here is a way to compute nutritional content from them.

Suppose A:B is an ingredient - nutritional content table, such as

```
Ingredient  Protein
spaghetti   2
sauce       4
eggs        10
cheese      6
marjoram    2
```

and cell E2 has "150 spaghetti, 30 sauce, 5 marjoram, 20 cheese". The following formula computes the amount of protein in this recipe:

```
=sumproduct(
  vlookup(split(regexreplace(E2, "[\d\W]+", " "), " "), A:B, 2, 0), 
  split(regexreplace(E2, "\D+", " "), " ")
)
```

Explanation:

- the first split-regexreplace combo extracts all words from the recipe, by replacing the digits and punctuation with spaces and then splitting by space. We get the array of four words: spaghetti, sauce, marjoram, cheese
- then, vlookup looks up the protein content (column 2 in range A:B). If you also have fat, calories, carbs, etc, then the lookup range will be A:E and the column to use will be one of 2, 3, 4, 5.
- the second split-regexreplace extracts the amounts of ingredients, it removes everything that is not a digit from the formula
- `sumproduct` adds the products of these two arrays, computing the total protein content.

All this is fragile because of regex-based parsing of text, and will break if the string deviates from expected format; for example, if a recipe calls for "1 1/2 tablespoons of sugar". In which case, see the first paragraph.